# Amazon RDS: Cannot connect to Oracle DB SQL Plus

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, rds

I can successfully telnet to my RDS Oracle DB, but keep getting the following error when connecting from SQL Plus: **"ERROR:ORA-12570: TNS:packet reader failure"**

> c:\tools\instantclient_12_1>sqlplus mydb/mypassword@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my-oracle-micro-20gb.cpcmdej7ob7l.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYDB1)))
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri May 8 11:41:00 2015
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle. All rights reserved.
>
> ERROR:
> ORA-12570: TNS:packet reader failure

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It never worked? Or it stop working at some point? Also, you're telnetting on port 1521 and from the same machine which fails to connect with SQL Plus, right?

Comment: It never worked. And yes, it is the same machine for SQL plus & Telnet...

Comment: Have you reviewd [this ask tom doc](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:424289000563)?